# Problema con Action Bar - JavaNullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Buen día,

Soy nuevo en programación y en Android también, por lo que espero que no sea un problema muy tonto, pero no he encontrado solución a esto por ningún lado.

El problema es que mi aplicación se cierra al tratar de cambiar el actionbar. El cambio del actionbar se hace con un `NavigationItemSelectedListener` mediante un switch, dependiendo de cuál ítem sea seleccionado, ya sea "Home", "Perfil" o "Usuarios", utilizando `actionBar.setTitle`

Lo raro es que en el método `OnCreate()` uso el mismo método  `actionBar.setTitle` y funciona correctamente.

Este es el código:

```java
public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Firebase auth
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    ActionBar actionBar;
    BottomNavigationView navigationView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

        //Action bar y el titulo
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Perfil");

        //Inicializar
        firebaseAuth = firebaseAuth.getInstance();

        //Inicializar Views
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(selectedListener);

        //Default, al iniciar
        //Home Fragment transaction
        actionBar.setTitle("Home");
        HomeFragment fragment1 = new HomeFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft1 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft1.replace(R.id.content, fragment1, "");
        ft1.commit();

    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener selectedListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                    //Manejar los clicks en los items
                    switch(menuItem.getItemId()){
                        case R.id.nav_home:
                            //Home Fragment transaction
                            actionBar.setTitle("Inicio");
                            HomeFragment fragment1 = new HomeFragment();
                            FragmentTransaction ft1 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            ft1.replace(R.id.content, fragment1, "");
                            ft1.commit();
                            return true;
                        case R.id.nav_profile:
                            //Home Fragment transaction
                            actionBar.setTitle("Perfil");
                            ProfileFragment fragment2 = new ProfileFragment();
                            FragmentTransaction ft2 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            ft2.replace(R.id.content, fragment2, "");
                            ft2.commit();
                            return true;
                        case R.id.nav_users:
                            //Users Fragment transaction
                            actionBar.setTitle("Usuarios");
                            UsersFragment fragment3 = new UsersFragment();
                            FragmentTransaction ft3 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            ft3.replace(R.id.content, fragment3, "");
                            ft3.commit();
                            return true;
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            };

    private void checkUserStatus(){
        //Obtener el usuario actual
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(user!=null){
            //El usuario esta logeado, no cambiar activity
            //Modificar TV con email del usuario


        } else {
            // El usuario no esta logeado, cambiar a MainActivity
            startActivity(new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        //Verificar al iniciar App
        checkUserStatus();
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //Menu inflable
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    //Manejar clicks en el menu

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        //Obtener id del menu
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id == R.id.action_logout){
            firebaseAuth.signOut();
            checkUserStatus();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Este es el XML del activity:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".DashboardActivity">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_nav">


    </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>




</LinearLayout>
```

Este es el menú que se usa:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:title="Home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
        android:title="Profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile_black"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_users"
        android:title="Users"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_users_black"/>


</menu>
```

El error que recibo es este:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que defines la variable dos veces. Una a nivel de la clase:

```
//Firebase auth
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
ActionBar actionBar; // ----> Aquí defines una pero no la inicializas, así que
                     //       de momento apunta a null.
BottomNavigationView navigationView;
```

Luego en `onCreate` creas otra variable que aunque se llame igual, es otra, y por más valor que le des, cuando termina la función `onCreate` la variable pierde el ámbito y se destruye. Mientras que la otra variable sigue a `null`.

Esto tienes en `onCreate`:

```
//Action bar y el titulo
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); //--->Variable nueva toma valor.
actionBar.setTitle("Perfil");
```

Así que cuando llegas al listener y ejecutas esto:

```
case R.id.nav_home:
    //Home Fragment transaction
    actionBar.setTitle("Inicio");
```

`actionBar` está a `null`.

**Solución**:

Eliminar la definición de la variable en `onCreate` y solo darle valor a la variable de la clase:

```
//Action bar y el titulo
actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); //--->Variable de la clase toma valor.
actionBar.setTitle("Perfil");
```